# how to get data from all pages from api using axios in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to fetch data from an api and , the api return multple pages 1st page has 10 objects and remaining data in the next pages. Now when i make a normal axios api request it is only giving me the first 10 data from first page how can i get all data from all pages at once.

This is what i tried.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getJobs } from "../service/jobs";

const MyTable = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    getJobs()
      .then(function (response) {
        setData(response.data.data.data);
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Jobs error", e);
      });
  }, []);

 

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div>
      {data &&
        data.map((d, key) => (
          <div key={key} className="d-flex">
            <h1>{d.id}</h1>
            <h1>{d.job_title}</h1>
            
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyTable;
```

this is the api response

```
data: 
current_page: 1
data: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
first_page_url: "http://api/api/v1/jobs?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 2
last_page_url: "http://api/api/v1/jobs?page=2"
links: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
next_page_url: "http://api/api/v1/jobs?page=2"
path: "http://api/api/v1/jobs"
per_page: 10
prev_page_url: null
to: 10
total: 13
```

getjobs() function code

```
export function getJobs() {
  return axiosClient.get("/jobs");
}
```

axiosClient

```
const axiosClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: api_url_v1,
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    }
  });
```

Comment: Do you mean that the server isn't returning the data you expect?  Or that you want to know what options the server has for returning more data?  That's entirely up to the server.  Have you checked the server-side code, or contacted whoever maintains it?

Comment: Actually the api return data correctly but only from 1st page i dont know how to get data from all pages   this is the reponse from the api   data: 
current_page: 1
data: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
first_page_url: "http://api/api/v1/jobs?page=1"
from: 1
last_page: 2
last_page_url: "http://api/api/v1/jobs?page=2"
links: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
next_page_url: "http://api/api/v1/jobs?page=2"
path: "http://api/api/v1/jobs"
per_page: 10
prev_page_url: null
to: 10
total: 13    see there is a second page i want that data too

Comment: What you're showing in that comment includes a literal URL for getting data from the "second page".  Did you try using that?

Comment: How can i do that. I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

This code is going to be a fairly rough outline of the process, not something you can be expected to just copy/paste and have it work without modification...

If you want to fetch multiple "pages" of records *and don't know how many pages there are* then you're going to need to mimic the effect of a loop, but with React component re-renders instead.  The main state elements are:

1. The list of items that you're building.
2. An indication of the "next page".

The process would essentially be to use `useEffect` to fetch the "next page" on every render, relying on the second data element above for knowing whether or not to do so.

For example, consider this state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState('http://api/api/v1/jobs?page=1');
```

You could then create a `useEffect` which has `nextPage` as a dependency, and within that effect you would fetch `nextPage`, add its contents to `data`, and update `nextPage` if there's another page of data indicated by the server.

The important part is that these updates should only happen *conditionally* within that effect, so it eventually stops when the last "page" has been reached.  For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Only fetch if nextPage is not null
  if (nextPage) {
    axiosClient.get(nextPage)
      .then(response => {
        // add the response to the data state
        setData(prev => [...prev, ...response.data.data.data]);

        // update the nextPage state
        // (I'm guessing on the property, check your data structure)
        setNextPage(response.data.next_page_url);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Jobs error", e);
      });
  }
}, [nextPage]);
```

Once you have the basic structure working, you can refactor however you like.  For example, if you want to extract the `axios` operation into its own function like you already have, you would just need to pass to that function some value indicating the "next page" such that you could update the URL being fetched in that function.